# How do I associate a user with an auto-renewable subscription involving Apple's status notifications?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storekit

How do I associate an auto-renewable subscription in a way that lets me know which notifications are for which users in MY database? Is there some sort of id from the original receipt that I can store as a field for a User?

It is great that I know when a user cancels or renews, etc but it doesn't help that I am not sure which user this is happening for.

When you [visit the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html) and scroll down to **Status Update Notifications**, you'll notice that status notifications do have an `original_transaction_id` field, is this something that persists and can be relied on?

Comment: Users in database.. I think you must be knowing  that in-app subscription / purchases are associated with iTunesConnect account & not app users.
If you've subscribed to 1 auto-renewable subscription ,then validating receipt will always give you purchased status irrespective of app user.

In case you are presenting different subscriptions as different product ids .But how will you manage all the product IDs in iTunesConnect?Could you please provide more detail on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use `original_transaction_id`. It's property saved for all renews.

If the user cancels their subscription and buys a new subscription, then `original_transaction_id` will change.

However, if the user upgrades or downgrades their subscription, `original_transaction_id` will *not* change.

This is supported on modern versions of iOS, including iOS 10.

Another way to do it is to save an array of `transaction_id` values and associate these with user accounts. Depending on your needs, this might work better for you.

UPD by [Stafox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187064/stafox): time-to-time `original_transaction_id` may changes after renew and may still the same after cancel and resubscribe.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! The apple docs made it sound like it was a legacy field for iOS6 users.

Comment: @AppreciateIt no, it's worked on iOS 10 :) Other way, - you can save array of transaction_id and associate with user. May be this way well be better for you.

Comment: @AppreciateIt
if you knew Subscription status URL, plz guide me below problem 
 stackoverflow.com/questions/46218509/… Above is my question. I set Subscription Status URL in my APP in iTunes account like xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php I also successfully tested nscurl --ats-diagnostics xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php I have set Subscription Status URL, implement php code to get JSOB but I can not get response, I get response like [ ] \nArray\n

Comment: @VladimirPrigarin
if you knew Subscription status URL, plz guide me below problem stackoverflow.com/questions/46218509/… Above is my question. I set Subscription Status URL in my APP in iTunes account like xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php I also successfully tested nscurl --ats-diagnostics xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php I have set Subscription Status URL, implement php code to get JSOB but I can not get response, I get response like [ ] \nArray\n

Comment: @AnkurPatel I also could not get the subscription status url to work, I don't think it works for anyone. Submitted a bug report to Apple

Comment: @AppreciateIt did you get any reply from Apple server 
are you used php code to get JSON Response ?
are we needed any extra code , extra setting on our iOS, Objective C app side?

Comment: It's not true. OT_ID may changes after renew and may still the same after cancel and resubscribe

Comment: @Stafox proofs?

Comment: @VladimirPrigarin for example, https://imgur.com/kvm0O22
I work about 2 years with subs, and have more than 2mln iOS receipts. So I caught a lot of strange and non-documented things (even transaction_id may changes time-to-time :) )

Comment: @Stafox Oh... it's interesting:) Thx for really helpful information! If I have  a problem with subscriptions, a will write you. It's possible?

Comment: Ok. no problem.