# Offering auto-renew subscriptions to multiple apps

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

As is confirmed by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/) it should be possible to add the same auto-renew iap to multiple apps. I have an iPhone and an iPad app in which I want to offer one auto-renew iap, which when purchased once will unlock both apps. 
To handle the subscription across both apps, I've setup a server where the auto-renew receipt is uploaded to once it's been purchased by the user. Each time a user opens one of these apps, a connection is made to the server to check if there is an active subscription, if there is one the app is unlocked, if not the 'buy a subscription' screen should pop up.

Now the question I am facing is how do I identify each user on the server when he checks for an active subscription ? How do I know when a user has bought a subscription before in on of the other apps ?

Comment: As it says in the document you linked to, it is your responsibility to identify users; their suggestion is to create an account system so that users log in to your apps. You can then link the subscription to the account on your server.

Comment: Actually I prefer not to let the user go through that hassle of creating an account before purchasing an iap.

Comment: Then how are you going to identify that you have the same user? iOS can't give you anything to identify the same user from different apps. If the apps are from the same publisher you can use `identifierForVendor` but this only works on a single device and you need to handle re-installs.  If your server could handle multiple receipt to identifier mappings this could work; the user would need to restore purchase on re-install or on their other devices to establish the additional receipt-ID4V mapping on your server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I associate a user with an auto-renewable subscription involving Apple's status notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124650/how-do-i-associate-a-user-with-an-auto-renewable-subscription-involving-apples) And what my backend does is allow the user to be an anonymous user AKA I generate their username and associate a session token with them, no password/login needed unless they 'finish sign up'.

Comment: @AppreciateIt could you elaborate in an answer ? How do you prevent from the user sharing his username and let others download the subscription for free ?

Comment: @Oysio essentially the session token represents a code that the server generates and stores so that it identifies a particular installation/device as a particular user

Comment: @AppreciateIt I see. I assume this would stop working once the user changes devices.

Comment: Yeah unless they finish sign up and login to the new device.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an iPhone and an iPad app in which I want to offer one auto-renew iap, which when purchased once will unlock both apps

I assume the iPhone and iPad app is not an universal app. Meaning, they do not share the same bundle ID. If it is an universal app, the receipt containing renewable subscriptions will be delivered as part of the App Store download.

> how do I identify each user on the server

Since you don't want to bother the user with signing up for yet another account, you can persist the most recent active subscription date in iCloud. NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is perfect for this. From a quick network inspection, this is how Ulysses seems to be handling universal subscriptions (they seem to be using a combination of iCloud KVS and CloudKit to determine if a user has already purchased a subscription on their Mac or iOS app). However, it now becomes an issue of whether your users have iCloud accounts.